# Accessing AWS EC2 instances through ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up two instances under an elastic load balancer, but cannot figure out how I'm supposed to access the instances through the load balancer.

I've set up the instances with a security group to allow access from anywhere to certain ports. I can access the instances directly using their "Public DNS" (publicdns) host name and the port PORT:

http://[publicdns]:PORT/

The load balancer contains the two instances and they are both "In Service" and it's forwarding the port (PORT) onto the same port on the instances.

However, if I request

http://[dnsname]:PORT (where dnsname is the A Record listed for the ELB)

it doesn't connect to the instance (connection times out).

Is this not the correct way to use the load balancer, or do I need to do anything to allow access to the load balancer? The only mention of security groups in relation to the load balancer is to *restrict* access to the instances to the load balancer only, but I don't want that. I want to be able to access them individually as well.

I'm sure there's something simple and silly that I've forgotten, not realised or done wrong :P

Cheers,
  Svend.

---

Extra info added:

The Port Configuration for the Load Balancer looks like this (actually 3 ports):

10060 (HTTP) forwarding to 10060 (HTTP)
Stickiness: Disabled(edit)

10061 (HTTP) forwarding to 10061 (HTTP)
Stickiness: Disabled(edit)

10062 (HTTP) forwarding to 10062 (HTTP)
Stickiness: Disabled(edit)

And it's using the standard/default elb security group (amazon-elb-sg).

The instances have two security groups. One external looking like this:

22 (SSH)          0.0.0.0/0
10060 - 10061       0.0.0.0/0
10062              0.0.0.0/0

and one internal, allowing anything within the internal group to communicate on all ports:

0 - 65535   sg-xxxxxxxx (security group ID)

Not sure it makes any difference, but the instances are m1.small types of image ami-31814f58.

---

Something that might have relevance:

My health check used to be HTTP:PORT/ but the load balancer kept saying that the instances were "Out of Service", even though I seem to get a 200 response on the request on that port.

I then changed it to TCP:PORT and it then changed to say they were "In Service".

Is there something very specific that should be returned for the HTTP one, or is it simply a HTTP 200 response that's required? ... and does the fact that it wasn't working hint towards why the load balancing itself wasn't working either?

Comment: I tried this as well, using the web console:

1) Created a security group that allows all access from all sources.
2) Created new t1.micro instance, using the new security group.
3) SSH onto group and netcat "Hello" on port 80.
4) Check that I can get the "Hello" HTTP 200 response directly (yes)
5) Create load balancer and assign this instance.
6) Set health check as TCP:80 (HTTP:80/ doesn't work).
7) Try accessing load balancer. Not working.
8) Feel sad :(

Comment: How are you trying to access the loadbalancer. When I make my requests to the loadbalancer I'm requesting a file index.html. Its possible the loadbalancer doesn't like sending an empty file?

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit, and it does seem that the issue is with my load balancers health check. Just getting a 200 response code doesn't seem to be enough. I achieved that before by using netcat (echo "Hello" | nc -l PORT), but that didn't work. Changing it to use TCP made it appear "In Service", but might not have worked. I just created a small instance, and as soon as I installed httpd and had it reply with a proper html file (http reply), it worked! :) Thank you all. On Monday I'll verify it is the problem (bwight, do you want to write it in answer form, so I can tick it if so :) )

Comment: After extra verifications I can confirm that the problem _is_ that the health check isn't of the proper format. I'm not sure exactly what is required, but can say this much: Using an empty 200 response from my tomcat server running on the instance does _not_ work, but installing httpd and returning a static (even empty) html file _does_ work. I've been looking at the response headers, and the only thing I can think of is that the tomcat one is missing a content-type...

Comment: Sounds like this is maybe something you could bring to the forums at amazon. One of the amazon employee's can probably give you a good answer if you present the facts we've gathered here. Usually they're pretty helpful if its not just a "OMG the loadbalancer doesnt work!"

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have everything set up correctly. Are they the same ports going into the loadbalancer as the instance? Or are you forwarding the request to another port?

As a side note, when I configure my loadbalancers I don't generally like to open up my instances on any port for the general public. I only allow the loadbalancer to make requests to those instances. I've noticed in the past that many people will make malicious requests to the IP of the instance trying to find a security breach. I've even seen people trying to brute force login into my windows machines....

To create a security rule only for the loadbalancers run the following commands and remove any other rules you have in the security-group for the port the loadbalancer is using. If you're not using the commandline to run these commands then just let me know which interface you're trying to use and i can try to come up with a sample that will work for you.

```
elb-create-lb-listeners <load-balancer> --listener "protocol=http, lb-port=<port>, instance-port=<port>"
ec2-authorize <security-group>  -o amazon-elb-sg -u amazon-elb
```

Back to your question. Like I said, the steps you explained are correct, opening the port on the instance and forwarding the port to the instance should be enough. Maybe you need to post the full configuration of your instance's security group and the loadbalancer so that I can see if there is something else affecting your situation.

Comment: I could not reproduce your errors. I tried the same setup as you with the same ports and it seems to be working fine. Took the loadbalancer a few minutes to start working though.

Comment: Hmm. Sure I just read you said you saw the same issue :P ...I've set up the instances, security groups and load balancer using the java api. I'll have a go at setting it up via the web interface, to see if there's any difference...

Comment: I saw the same issue and then it seemed to work a minute later. I think the instance still wasn't active on the loadbalancer when i tried the first time.

Comment: Do you know any way to limit the connection to a specific elastic load balancer. It seems this allows access to any load balancer.

Comment: From what I understand only ELBs inside a VPC can be launched with a custom security group. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLoadBalancer.html

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created a script that will reproduce the same exact steps that i'm using. This assumes you're using linux as an operating system and that the AWS CLI tools are already installed. If you don't have this setup already I recommend starting a new Amazon Linux micro instance and running the script from there since they have everything already installed.

1. Download the X.509 certificate files from amazon https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
2. Copy the certificate files to the machine where you will run the commands
3. Save two variables that are required in the script

   ```
   aws_account=<aws account id>
   keypair="<key pair name>"
   ```
4. Export the certificates as environmental variables

   ```
   export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=<private_Key_file>
   export EC2_CERT=<cert_file>
   export EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   ```
5. Create the security groups

   ```
   ec2-create-group loadbalancer-sg -d "Loadbalancer Test group"
   ec2-authorize loadbalancer-sg -o loadbalancer-sg -u $aws_account
   ec2-authorize loadbalancer-sg -p 80 -s 0.0.0.0/0
   ```
6. Create the user-data-file for the instance so that apache is started and the index.html file is created

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/temp/ 
   echo '#! /bin/sh
   yum -qy install httpd
   touch /var/www/html/index.html
   /etc/init.d/httpd start' > ~/temp/user-data.sh
   ```
7. Start the new instance and save the instanceid

   ```
   instanceid=`ec2-run-instances ami-31814f58 -k "$keypair" -t t1.micro -g loadbalancer-sg -g default -z us-east-1a -f ~/temp/user-data.sh | grep INSTANCE | awk '{ print $2 }'`
   ```
8. Create the loadbalancer and attach the instance

   ```
   elb-create-lb test-lb --availability-zones us-east-1a --listener "protocol=http, lb-port=80, instance-port=80"
   elb-register-instances-with-lb test-lb --instances $instanceid
   ```
9. Wait until your instance state in the loabalancer is "InService" and try to access the urls